# How to make a new place listed internationally so I can pick it in Facebook as hometown?

Tags: facebook, location

How do you make a new place listed internationally so it can be picked in Facebook as hometown?

I live in Batam Island, Indonesia. It's really a particular place in the country.

Answer (score 1):

You must `create a page` for it so that you can select it as your hometown